# Light stays on no matter if switch is on or off

Tags: lighting, switch, light-fixture

I recently replaced a chain pull light fixture in my closet with a recessed light.  Instead of a chain pull, I installed a new switch.  The light fixture had two cables coming in.  Each had a black, white, and copper wire.  I ran new romex from the new switch box to the light fixture and tied the wires together based on color.  When turning the breaker on, the light comes on but can’t be turned off with the switch.

Comment: Anywhere that has adopted NEC2011 or later, you need /3 cable (white-red-black-ground) for a switch loop. And "matching colors" is NOT how electricity is done, particularly in switch loops. Go check out a book from the library on basic home wiring (but if it's old, find a newer reference for switch loop wiring.)

Comment: How were the wires connected _prior_ to replacing the fixture?

Comment: Hopefully you've learned that you're not qualified to do electrical work. Please take Ecnerwal's advice and do some learning before undertaking any more wiring projects. At a bare minimum you should've wired it as the old light was. You also need to know how to make secure connections so you don't start a fire.

Answer (score 6):

You connected:

- Incoming black to light black to switch black
- Incoming white to light white to switch white

That results in the light always on. the switch is *parallel* to the light and has no effect.

What you need to do is:

- Figure out which cable at the light is "incoming". Disconnect the blacks from each other. Use a non-contact voltage tester to see which one is hot. That's the "incoming" cable.
- Connect incoming black to switch white. Mark the switch white (in light fixture box and in switch box) with black tape.
- Connect incoming white to light white.
- Connect switch black to light black.

But you have another problem. Unless you are in Kansas or Indiana, your state is on a version of the NEC which requires neutral in new switch boxes. So you have to replace the 2-wire Romex with 3-wire (black/red/white). And then the wiring becomes:

- Connect incoming black to switch black.
- Connect incoming white to switch white and light white.
- Connect switch red to light black.
- In the switch box, cap the white neutral wire. You may need it someday if you add a smart switch.

Comment: a switch that is parallel to a light would trip the breaker whenever the switch is turned on

Comment: @jsotola You're right! Which makes me wonder now how exactly the switch was connected. Because if it was black to hot & light black, white to neutral & light neutral, then when the switch is on it would be a dead short.

Comment: Perhaps it's a smart switch with a white wire, and a switched hot wire not connected to anything given the lack of proper switch loop wiring.

Comment: @jsotola OP doesn't mention tying the wires to the switch. They may be tied together with an unconnected switch as a faceplate.

Comment: Am I correct to understand that the neutral thing is just to support 'smart switches' and not for any safety reason whatsoever?  If so, I get it but in an older home, I think it's a bit ridiculous to have to pull wires in order to support something you don't want or need.

Comment: Code is code. Since 2011 this has been code, so except for KS and IN that are still (at last check) on 2008, it is a requirement. You are **not** required to retrofit existing switch loops. But if you create a **new** switch loop then this is required. Just like you are not required to retrofit GFCI into existing kitchen, bathroom, laundry room, etc. but if you add any **new** receptacles (i.e., installing a receptacle in a location that had none before, not a direct replacement for some other reason) then they must be GFCI protected. The idea is that the types of devices that require neutral

Comment: are becoming more and more common, so when you are doing the work anyway, do the extra bit. It is the same labor to run a /3 cable as a /2. Prices vary depending on where you buy and how you buy, but for example currently at Home Depot 12/3 250 ft. vs. 12/2 250 ft. is a differential of $0.24 per foot. So if it is a 25 ft. run (enough for a switch loop in most typical residential non-mansion rooms) that's a grand total of $ 6 extra, which (a) satisfies code and (b) makes things a **LOT** easier if you or a future owner ever needs that neutral.